# Is there anything like an Objective-C block in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm just learning Java, and I've developed apps in Objective-C before. I like the concept of "blocks", because they allow code to be ran after something happens.

For example, to execute a block after a certain amount of time in a SpriteKit app that calls a method `helloWorld` from scene `myScene`:

```
[myScene runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:5], [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [myScene helloWorld];
}]]]];
```

Is there anything like a block in Java? If so, how would I use it? What's the syntax to...

- use it as a function parameter?
- call said block in the function?
- assign a value to the block?

I've heard a little bit about "closures," but I'm not so sure what they are or how to use them.

Comment: Look into lambdas in Java.

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+objective-c+blocks) before posting a question like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, the way to do this is to use an interface. The most basic interface for this is `Runnable` which has a method `run`.

> What's the syntax to...
>
> use it as a function parameter?

```
void foo(Runnable r)
```

> call said block in the function?

```
r.run();
```

> assign a value to the block?

Before Java 8 you had to do something like this:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
Runnable r = () -> { // do something }
```

An expression involving `->` is called a lambda. The brakets `()` are where you would write any parameters, but the method `run` of `Runnable` doesn't have any parameters. You can also pass a `Runnable` to a method without mentioning `Runnable`:

```
foo(() -> { // do something });
```

Java 8 introduced many, many new interfaces where the method can return a value or accept parameters.