# Is there something like a Runnable in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda

I'm new to Unity and I don't know very much about it. However, I've played around with Java and Objective-C in the past; two object-oriented C-based programming languages that are very much like the C# Unity uses.

Objective-C has [blocks](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/blocks) that are variables that allow you to store a function inside of them and call them later. When used in practice, you can use blocks as function parameters and class properties, saving a programmer "`if`" statements and instead simply calling the block.

An example of that syntax would be (taken from the linked tutorial site):

```
// Declare a block variable
double (^distanceFromRateAndTime)(double rate, double time);

// Create and assign the block
distanceFromRateAndTime = ^double(double rate, double time) {
   return rate * time;
};

// Call the block
double dx = distanceFromRateAndTime(35, 1.5);

NSLog(@"A car driving 35 mph will travel %.2f miles in 1.5 hours.", dx);
```

Java has the [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) class, which is the basis of its multithreading structure. (`Thread` inherits from `Runnable`.) I learned about that class from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997887/is-there-anything-like-an-objective-c-block-in-java) I asked. There are two ways of making a `Runnable`: The Java 8 way of using lambdas...

```
Runnable r = () -> { System.out.println("This is just an example!"); }
```

The Java 8 using lambdas as a function parameter...

```
void someFunction(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
}

// In a method, not sure about the semicolons
someFunction( () -> { System.out.println("This will work, too!"); });
```

And finally, pre-Java 8...

```
Runnable r = Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
         System.out.println("Yet another example");
    }
}
```

My question is, how would I go about achieving this in Unity's variant of C#?

Comment: `Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("lambda action");`, and the asynchronous operation `Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("thread pooled"));`.

Comment: @Mephy thank you! I just needed to learn about the `Action` class. Can I put curly brackets around the running code and have a multiline statement?

Comment: Hi DDPWNAGE.  One thing, it's critical to understand that Unity is ***absolutely single threaded***.  There are no other threads and you cannot access any other threads. (Note that you may have seen "coroutines". These have utterly no connection to threads in any way.)

Comment: Another problem you may face is that in the first paragraph you mention "object-oriented". It's critical to realise that Unity is absolutely NOT object-oriented, it is an ECS system. It does not have **any concepts even vaguely similar to inheritance** and has utterly nothing to do with OO.  (Essay on that http://stackoverflow.com/a/37243035/294884 ) As it happens, the (current) programming language (c#) used to *write behaviors for* Unity GameObects, happens to be, an OO language. But that's irrelevant. They could change tomorrow to using Lisp :) or something and it would not affect Unity.

Comment: @JoeBlow That explains JavaScript. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Action delegate would be the equivalent, without multi-threading aspect. You can use an expression by specifying the parameter list, the '=>' symbol and then the resulting expression, which can also be a block. Func can be used instead if the return type is non-void.

```
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("a");
Action b = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
Action c = (x, y, z) => {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    Console.WriteLine(z);
}
Func<int, int, int> add = (x, y) => x + y; // last type is return-type
```

Many multithreading libraries will accept actions and funcs as parameters, including the core TPL, which includes method likes `Task.Run` and `Task.ForEach`. When operating os collections, the PLINQ extension (Parallel Linq) is a great tool that chains funcs together.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! 

Comment: HI @DDPWNAGE althogh you have ticked this answer, I must emphasize again that Unity is ***utterly single threaded***.  You appear to be on a totally wrong track.  No Unity engineer would ask the question you're asking, if that makes sense.  Unity does not have threads.  There is absolutely no "thread-like idiom" in Unity.  You never think in threads and threads will be totally uninvolved in your Unity working life.

Comment: Not necessarily true. You can use multi-threaded code in Unity3D as long as you don't call the Unity API, which is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

It is called `Action` in C#, and you use the lambda operator `=>`  :

```
Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("This is just an example!");
```

You can also pass it around :

```
// single line statement doesn't need to be wrapped in a {code block}, and you don't need the `;` at the end
SomeFunction(() => Console.WriteLine("This will work, too!"));

SomeFunction(() =>
{
    //multiline statements
    Console.WriteLine("This will work, too!");
    Console.WriteLine("This will work, too!x2");
    Console.WriteLine("This will work, too!x3");
});

void SomeFunction(Action action)
{
    action();
}
```